# Can Basic Law $V$ be derived from Leibniz's Law in Second-Order Logic without comprehension principles?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

Consider Basic Law $V$:

$\hat x$$F$($x$)=$\hat x$$G$($x$)$\equiv$($\forall$$x$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)

At first glance, it seems to have the same form as Leibniz's law

$x$=$y$$\equiv$($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$y$) (if one substitutes '$x$' for '$y$' and one assumes '$x$' satisfies both '$F$ ' and '$G$')

Since it is claimed that the logic of Frege's *Begriffsschrift* is second-order logic without comprehension principles, if, given second-order logic without comprehension principles with the extra axioms

$x$=$x$

$x$=$y$$\equiv$($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$y$)

and a 'course-of-values' operator '$\hat x$' that gives, when applied to $F$, $G$, the first-order objects that satisfy $F$, $G$; can one derive Basic Law $V$?  If not, what further assumptions must one make in order to derive Basic Law $V$ and are these further assumptions valid?

Comment: In Frege's system there are "comprehension principles"; they are "embedded" into *Grundgesetze*'s rule of uniform substitution.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Interesting.   How so?  Also, does Frege realize they are so "embedded"?

Comment: You can see [Frege's Rule of Substitution](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/rule-substitution.html); in general, for Frege's logic, see Zalta's entry on [Frege's Theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/).

Comment: Leibniz's law is Basic Law III of *Gg*.

Comment: BL V and L's law are only apparently similar: the first one quantify on "objects", while the second quantify on "functions". And the issue with F's original system is exactly in the assumption that for every function there is a corresponding object (its *wertverläufe*).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  I find it interesting that Zalta states that the rule of uniform substitution is logically equivalent to the Comprehension Principle for Concepts without referwnce to Basic Law $V$....

Comment: I think that you cannot derive BL V from L's law without extra assumptions: SOL (equality axioms included) is consistent, while Frege's system (with BL V) is not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  It should be noted that in Manuel Bremer's preprint "Frege's Basic Law ($V$) and Cantor's Theorem", he writes Basic Law $V$ this way:  ($\forall$$ F$)($\forall $$G$)($\hat e$$F$($e$)=$\hat e$$G$($e$)$\equiv$($\forall$$x$)($F$($x$)$\equiv$$G$($x$))).  Is this not a correct way of writing Basic Law $V$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Consider the following 'derivation':  From $x$=$y$$\equiv$($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$y$) one can derive $x$=$x$$\equiv$($\forall$$x$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$x$) by substituting '$x$' for '$y$'.  Assuming  '$x$'  has another property ' $G$', one can also write $x$=$x$$\equiv$($\forall$$G$)($G$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$).  Since $x$=$x$ $\land$ $x$=$x$ $\equiv$ $x$=$x$, one can write (because $\equiv$ is symmetric)  ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$\equiv$$G$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$) $\equiv$ $x$=$x$.  From this, one can derive

Comment: (cont.) ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$) $\equiv$ $x$=$x$ (as one can see, this is getting 'close' to deriving Basic Law $V$).  From here, the question now becomes: how to handle the appropriate substitutions and definitions of 'objects' in order to derive Basic Law $V$.  Can one appropriately arrange 'substitions' and 'definitions of objects' in SOL in order to derive Basic Law $V$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  I believe I have the requisite substitutions.  From '$x$=$x$, since one can substitute '$z$' for  '$x$'  and '$x$' for '$z$, one can derive  $x$=$x$$\equiv$$z$=$z$.  Also, since $x$=$x$ and $z$=$z$ for all '$x$', '$z$', one has ($\forall$$x$)(x=x)$\equiv$($\forall$$z$)($z$=$z$).  Similarly,  since ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$ $x$=$x$, one can infer  ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($\forall$$x$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$ ($\forall$$x$)($x$=$x$), one has (by transitivity of $\equiv$),

Comment: (cont,) ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($\forall$$x$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$ ($\forall$$z$)($z$=$z$).  By Elimination of Quantifiers, one can eliminate '$\forall$$F$', '$\forall$$G$', and '$\forall$$z$'  and derive ($\forall$$x$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$ $z$=$z$.  Since '$x$' satisfies both '$F$' and '$G$', the terms '$\hat x$$F$$x$', '$\hat x$$G$$x$' refer to the same elements, one can seemingly (and here is where a problem may lie) substitute the term '$\hat x$$F$$x$' to one side of  '$z$=$z$' and $\hat x$$G$$x$ to the other to derive

Comment: (cont.) ($\forall$x)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$ $\hat x$$F$$x$=$\hat x$$G$$x$--Basic Law $V$.  I cannot  claim that this is a 'proof'--only a philosophical argument-- but this philosophical argument might suggest why Frege thought that Basic Law $V$ was a 'law of logic'.

Comment: In your first comment above you go from $x =y≡ (∀F)(Fx≡Fy)$ to $x=x≡(∀x)(Fx≡Fx)$. This is not correct; you must have $x=x≡(∀F)(Fx≡Fx)$. You cannot subst for a *function* var an *object* var.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Correct.  That was a typo.  It should read, "from $x$=$y$$\equiv$($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$y$) one can derive $x$=$x$$\equiv$($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$x$) by substituting '$x$' for '$y$'  " (that's the problem with the five minute edit rule for comments....)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  The rest should follow easily (except for possibly the substitutions  of  ' $\hat x$$F$$x$', $\hat x$$G$$x$ for either side of $z$=$z$....).

Comment: From the fact that $(∀F)(Fx≡Fx)$ and $(∀G)(Gx≡Gx)$ - that are obviously true - you **cannot** derive:  $(∀F)(∀G)(Fx≡Gx)≡ x=x$: the RHS is *valid*, while the LHS: $(∀F)(∀G)(Fx≡Gx)$ says that every object has all the properties... Think at $Odd(x) ≡ Even(x)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  I assume '$x$' satisfies both '$F$($x$)'  and '$G$($x$)'  so one can form ($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$x$)$\equiv$ $x$=$x$ $\equiv$ ($\forall$$G$)($G$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$).  I take it that this formula is invalid in general (obviously it is, since your example is correct).  What then is the correct way to write what I am trying to say, then?

Comment: Might it not be nice to turn some of this into an answer?  Reading a whole lot of comments is not nearly as pleasant.  And *Overflow has this way of attracting Google hits, so for posterity, could someone wrap this up?

Comment: @JacquesCarette:  Sorry to keep you on 'hold' so long, but I was waiting  for Mauro Allegranza to answer my comment before yours.  If '$x$' satisfies both '$F$($x$)' and '$G$($x$)', and since $x$=$x$ $\land$ $x$=$x$$\equiv$ $x$=$x$, is it correct to infer from ($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$x$)$\equiv$$x$=$x$ $\land$ ($\forall$$G$)($G$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$$x$=$x$, ($\forall$$F$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$F$$x$)$\equiv$($\forall$G$)($$G$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$$x$=$x$, and from this correctly infer ($\forall$$F$)($\forall$$G$)($F$$x$$\equiv$$G$$x$)$\equiv$$x$=$x$?  I believe it is,

Comment: (cont.) but I want to check.  If I have not made a mistake in logic here,  I will gladly post my comments as an answer.